# django-image-cropping not working

Tags: python, django, image

Trying to use [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping). I don't get any errors, I just have what looks like CharField in Django Admin instead of the django-image-cropping functionality:

[image]

base.py (settings):

```
from easy_thumbnails.conf import Settings as thumbnail_settings
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'image_cropping.thumbnail_processors.crop_corners',
) + thumbnail_settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS
```

added `easy_thumbnails` and `image_cropping` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

models.py:

```
from image_cropping import ImageRatioField
# ...
class Organization(models.Model):
    image_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True, help_text="blah")
    cropping = ImageRatioField('image_cover', '308x850')
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from image_cropping import ImageCroppingMixin

class OrganizationAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal=['categorys']
    #...

admin.site.register(Organization, OrganizationAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `OrganizationAdmin` twice in `admin.py`. Once, correctly, subclassing ImageCroppingMixin and once without. Since the latter definition overwrites the former, you end up without the Mixin. This is how it should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from image_cropping import ImageCroppingMixin

class OrganizationAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal=['categorys']
    #...

admin.site.register(Organization, OrganizationAdmin)
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I get another error `IOError: decoder jpeg not available` that I'm working on now.

Comment: That's from easy-thumbnails - you probably installed Pillow without having libjpeg available. Check http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#simple-installation or simply uninstall Pillow and install the python-imaging module (if on Linux).